# Give PayPal buy now button special ID?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a service I am starting where it's paid. I want to give a PayPal payment a special id. The ID would be passed through IPN and I could read it so I can modify my mysql database with that special ID. If that all makes sense...

I am basically want to upgrade their account without having to do some complicated process which I have already tried where it would send the user the transaction ID and they would have to go to a special URL to change their account information.

See what I mean? How would I go about doing this?

Thanks,
Coulton

Comment: Are your paying customers registered users? Or do they just pay and get some kind of ID for the site?

Comment: They are current users. And they are getting a upgrade. So if I could pass the user's ID through the payment system and out through the IPN, that would be fantastic.

Comment: When the users pay and it is confirmed that the payment info is all good could you just assign them a different user class? I've seen some databases were like basic users are a 0 and an admin is say a 5. Each number grants different user privileges/abilities. The numbers usually go in order but are arbitrary really. Would it be possible to make a function like when the payment info is good they just take on a new user roll. You then validate the user name in the payment process via adding the username to a form via typing it in or via the cookie signed in. If payment info is good update status

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone else has a question on how to do it, I've found a way to fix it. When making your button, include this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://yourdomain.com/paypal/ipn.php?user_id=$user_id'>
```

So you can pass who has made the payment to the IPN via get. Simply use `$_GET['user_id']` to get the data (in my case a user_id). You can pass any variables you wish!

Answer (score 1):

I played around with this for ages before I have realized that you can only send the pre defined paypal variables and not make your own up.

These are listed here
[https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside](http://www.brianmoreau.com/articles/paypal_buy_now_button_sending_custom_variables.php)

One you can use for a custom variable is called 'custom'

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$twitId;?>">
```

You also need to ensure you use this button

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
```

You also need to turn on and set a URL for the Instant Payment Notification on PayPal

They call this as a listener but it really just sends the payment data to the paypal page.
Note this is not the URL the customer is returned to after payment completion as set in button preferences.

Retrieve the custom variable in PHP thus

```
$userID = $_POST[custom];
```

Full instructions here
http://www.brianmoreau.com/articles/paypal_buy_now_button_sending_custom_variables.php

Hope this saves you the many hours I spent on it.

This method also allows you to obtain the buyer details such as email and address and the transaction reference.

To view the full data paypal sends after payment by clicking on history, IPN history

Comment: It also works for "Buy Now" buttons on the return page. Probably worth noting security implications doing this; anything in "custom" could be changed by the user, so it needs to be verified afterwards.